# "Compile Error: Only Comments may appear after End Sub, End Function.." Access 2010 VBA

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2010

I am creating a form and I have created my first function in the VBA window.  The function creates Buttons.  After I type anything after the 'End function' I get an error- "Only comments appear after .."  What's wrong?  Am I putting the function in the wrong area?

Here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database 
Option Explicit

Function MainMenuOptions()

Dim frm As String
frm = "Main"

Dim SCFormB As Control
Dim SCSearchB As Control
Dim SCReportB As Control

Set SCFormB = CreateControl(frm, acOptionButton, , , , 0.5, 0.6, 1.5, 0.55)
Set SCSearchB = CreateControl(frm, acOptionButton, , , , 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.55)
Set SCReportB = CreateControl(frm, acOptionButton, , , , 0.5, 2.4, 1.5, 0.55)


End Function
```

Comment: Why would you need to type anything after *End Function* ?

Comment: Unless this is to save you time in development, it is not a good idea. You should not need to create buttons in a finalized project.

Comment: I am trying to make a dynamic form. On the main form window i inserted the function. I have done some reseaching and found that i am suppose to create a new module and insert the function there and then call the function from the module when needed. Is this advised? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you have extra code in your module which is outside of a function or sub. In the VBA editor select debug -> compile and it should highlight the offending code which you can remove or revise.

FYI: [CreateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237827%28v=office.12%29.aspx) uses twips(one 1440th of an inch) for left, top, width, and height. You may want to multiply the numbers you are using by about 1440.

Answer (score 6):

I have recently had this problem. I'm creating a new Shares/Derivatives trade and management application, and I'm making awesome progress on creating a form, when at one point, I starting getting this error for ALL of the _Click() handlers for the controls on the form. But, it was not happening for an _Enter() handler for one of the fields on the form. There was no extraneous text after any of the 'End' statements - at all! I discovered that, somehow, the incorrect LINE ENDINGS had made their way onto the ends of the 'End' statements.

The Fix: go to the end of each of your 'End' statements, hit DELETE until the next Sub statement comes up to the cursor (i.e., you now have the start of the next procedure on the same line as the previous proc's End statement), then hit ENTER to put the next Sub statement back on it's own line. This will ensure that you have the correct CR/LF (or whatever is required of that editor/compiler) at the ends of each of your event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Microsoft Office Dev Center [for this error message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251714.aspx) you get the following explanation:

> You placed executable code outside a procedure. Any nondeclarative
>   lines outside a procedure must begin with a comment delimiter (').
>   Declarative statements must appear before the first procedure
>   declaration. Comments are ignored when the code executes.

This means that the type of code you can write outside a Sub or Function is limited.

Comment: I read this on the site.  I guess i need to reseach on how to use vba and its modules.

Comment: I assume you have to use the modules to write functions and then call them on the main?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, and the solution was simple, however VBA's debugger threw me off the scent for a while. I had extra code after "End Sub" that needed deleting (copy and paste error), however rather than highlighting the extra code after the "End Sub" statement, the debugger highlighted the beginning of the Sub procedure, causing me to think that the error was between the opening statement of the highlighted Sub procedure and the "End Sub" ABOVE it, when in fact the error was after the "End Sub" of the highlighted sub procedure, so I needed to look well BELOW the highlighted text. So, in effect, VBA highlighted the beginning of a sub-procedure that was  entirely fine, rather than the issue immediately after it.

It's like someone leaving a bag of trash immediately outside your front door so you walk into the trash as soon as you walk through the door, and then you say "Huh, I need to move the trash" while pointing at the door.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, but I didn't have any code outside of my subs.  I was getting the error after Access would generate a piece of code (I was trying to add code for the NoData state of my report).  When I put a dummy comment below the End Sub that was having the issue it fixed the issue, at least for the last three compiles I have done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).